# How to implement pause/resume button click logic when downloading a file using HttpClient and HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, winforms

I just added a `btnPauseResume` to the form1 designer.

What I want to do is when the button default text is "Pause" and I click the button, just pause the current file download, and then switch the button text to "Resume", and next time when it is clicked, the download is resumed from the paused point.

This is the `HttpClientProgressExtensions` class:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Files_Downloader
{
    public static class HttpClientProgressExtensions
    {
        public static long contentSize = 0;

        public static async Task DownloadDataAsync(this HttpClient client, string requestUrl, Stream destination, IProgress<float> progress = null, IProgress<Tuple<long, TimeSpan>> speedProgress = null, IProgress<long> sizeProgress = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
            {
                var contentLength = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
                var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
                contentSize = contentLength.Value;

                using (var download = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    // no progress... no contentLength... very sad
                    if (progress is null || !contentLength.HasValue)
                    {
                        await download.CopyToAsync(destination);
                        return;
                    }

                    watch.Start();

                    var progressWrapper = new Progress<long>(totalBytes =>
                    {
                        var elapsed = watch.Elapsed;
                        progress.Report(GetProgressPercentage(totalBytes, contentLength.Value));

                        if (elapsed.TotalSeconds > 1)
                        {
                            var speed = (long)(totalBytes / elapsed.TotalSeconds);
                            speedProgress?.Report(Tuple.Create(totalBytes, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(speed)));
                            watch.Restart();
                        }

                        sizeProgress?.Report(totalBytes); // Report size progress
                    });

                    await download.CopyToAsync(destination, 81920, progressWrapper, cancellationToken);
                }
            }

            float GetProgressPercentage(float totalBytes, float currentBytes) => (totalBytes / currentBytes) * 100f;
        }

        static async Task CopyToAsync(this Stream source, Stream destination, int bufferSize, IProgress<long> progress = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            if (bufferSize < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(bufferSize));

            if (source is null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

            if (!source.CanRead)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"'{nameof(source)}' is not readable.");

            if (destination == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(destination));

            if (!destination.CanWrite)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"'{nameof(destination)}' is not writable.");

            var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            long totalBytesRead = 0;
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false)) != 0)
            {
                await destination.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                progress?.Report(totalBytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in `form1` the two methods that do the actual download:

```
private async Task DownloadFiles(string selectedFolder)
{
    foreach (string link in links.Distinct())
    {
        // Check if the link is not present in the set
        if (!uniqueLinks.Contains(link))
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(selectedFolder, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(link));

            // Check if the file doesn't exist on the hard drive and hasn't been downloaded before
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                // Your asynchronous download logic here
                await DownloadFile(link, selectedFolder);

                // Set the flag to indicate that a download occurred
                anyDownloadsOccurred = true;
            }

            // Add the link to the set after processing
            uniqueLinks.Add(link);
        }

        // Check if cancellation is requested
        cancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }

    // Any UI updates after the downloads are complete
    DownloadComplete();
}
```

and

```
private async Task DownloadFile(string docUrl, string path)
{
    // for the sake of the example, let's add a client definition here
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var filePath = Path.Combine(path, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(docUrl));

    downloadFilePath = filePath;

    // Use Invoke to update the UI with the current download link
    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        textBoxUrl.Text = docUrl;
    });

    // Setup your progress reporters
    var progress = new Progress<float>();
    var speedProgress = new Progress<Tuple<long, TimeSpan>>();
    var sizeProgress = new Progress<long>(); // Added for size progress

    progress.ProgressChanged += Progress_ProgressChanged;
    sizeProgress.ProgressChanged += SizeProgress_ProgressChanged; // Added event handler

    // Use the provided extension method with CancellationToken
    using (downloadStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        try
        {
            await client.DownloadDataAsync(docUrl, downloadStream, progress, speedProgress, sizeProgress, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (isCancel)
            {
                CloseFileStream();

                if (File.Exists(downloadFilePath))
                {
                    // Delete the partially downloaded file
                    File.Delete(downloadFilePath);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the top of `form1` I created a list of some links that are working for testing:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<string> links = new List<string>()
    {
        "https://hil-speed.hetzner.com/100MB.bin",
        "https://hil-speed.hetzner.com/100MB.bin",
        "https://hil-speed.hetzner.com/1GB.bin",
        "https://hil-speed.hetzner.com/10GB.bin"
    };

    private HashSet<string> uniqueLinks = new HashSet<string>();
    private const int MaxUniqueLinks = 1000; // Adjust as needed
    private bool anyDownloadsOccurred = false; // Flag to track whether any downloads occurred
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
    private string downloadFilePath;
    private bool isCancel = false;
    private FileStream downloadStream;
    private HttpWebRequest webRequest;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060348/pausing-a-download-thread  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995705/adding-pause-and-continue-ability-in-my-downloader

Comment: Note; if you stop calling `source.ReadAsync`, the OS will allow the tcp receive buffer to fill, then the remote server will stop sending more data. Allowing you to implement and short pause / resume without breaking the connection.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no sure if I can help you but this could be a way to adress your problem.

To pause and resume a download using `HttpClient`, you’ll need to manage the connection manually. When you click “Pause”, the connection is severed. To resume the download, you’ll need to initiate a new `HttpRequest`. This new request should specify the range of bytes that have already been downloaded. You can then append the newly downloaded data to the existing file. Here’s a sample code snippet to illustrate this:

```cs
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage { Method = HttpMethod.Get, RequestUri = [Some Uri] };
request.Headers.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(x, null); // From downloaded bytes (x) to End (null)
var response = await client.SendAsync(request); // Resend the request
```

You can’t use `GetAsync` on `HttpClient` for this purpose because you need to set the header of the `HttpRequest`.

Here’s an example of how you might implement it in your method:

```cs
public static async Task DownloadDataAsync(this HttpClient client, string requestUrl, Stream destination, IProgress<float> progress = null, IProgress<Tuple<long, TimeSpan>> speedProgress = null, IProgress<long> sizeProgress = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken), long? downloaded = null)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage { RequestUri = new Uri(requestUrl), Method = HttpMethod.Get };
    request.Headers.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(downloaded, null); 
    using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
    {
        var contentLength = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
        var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        contentSize = contentLength.Value;

        // Your code here...
        // Note: Change CopyToAsync to append if you start the request again!
    }
}
```

If you’re looking for a simpler solution, you could consider using the [DownloadAssistant NuGet-Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Shard.DownloadAssistant). It simplifies the process of resuming `HttpRequests` and is licensed under MIT.
This library doesn’t verify if a link appears multiple times in the list. Instead, it checks whether the download for a link is complete. If a file is fully downloaded, the library will not initiate another download for that file. However, it uses parallel downloads by default. If you don’t want this, you can create a new `RequestHandler` and set `StaticDegreeOfParallelism` to 1 or modify the default `RequestHandler`:

```cs
foreach (var handler in RequestHandler.MainRequestHandlers)
    handler.StaticDegreeOfParallelism = 1;
```

Here’s an example of how you might use this package to manage multiple downloads (your List):

```cs
// Define the links to download (your List)
string[] links = new string[]
{
    "https://hil-speed.hetzner.com/100MB.bin",
    "https://hil-speed.hetzner.com/100MB.bin",
    "https://hil-speed.hetzner.com/1GB.bin",
    "https://hil-speed.hetzner.com/10GB.bin"
};

// Create a container for all requests
ProgressableContainer<GetRequest> requestContainer = new();
// Create a cancellation token
CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new();

// For each link, create a request and add your settings
foreach (string link in links)
{
    GetRequestOptions options = new()
    {
        // Cancellation token. Cannot be resumed if canceled
        CancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token,
        // Path where the file should be stored
        DirectoryPath = "[Your path here]",
        // Reports the progress of the download
        Progress = new Progress<float>((downloadPercent) => { /*Some code here*/ }),
        // Callback when the request is completed
        RequestCompleated = (request, path) => { /*Some code here*/ },
        // Buffer length (Your buffer length)
        BufferLength = 81920,
        AutoStart = true,
    };

    GetRequest getRequest = new(link, options);
    requestContainer.Add(getRequest);
}

// Start or pause specific requests. Does not block the UI thread!
requestContainer[0].Pause();
requestContainer[0].Start();
requestContainer[1].Pause();
Task.Delay(1000).Wait();

// Start all requests in the container
requestContainer.Start();

// Merged progress of all requests in the container
requestContainer.Progress.ProgressChanged += (sender, completeDownloadPercent) => { /*Some code here*/ };

// Await a request or wait to finish
requestContainer[0].Task.Wait();

// Handle something your want requests
if(requestContainer[0].State == Requests.Options.RequestState.Failed)
{
    /*Some code here*/
}
```

I hope this helps clarify how to create pause and resume with `HttpClient`!

Comment: Web servers don't have to respect the range header and may send you the entire content, or respond with a 4xx error. A client MUST (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#status.206) double check the response Content-Range headers before saving the content.